# How to undo the last deployment to meteor.com?

Tags: meteor, deployment

I've my app delployed on `meteor.com`.

How can I rollback to the previous deployed state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use git, you can rollback your code by checking out a specific commit like so

```
git checkout <commit>
```

and then redeploy. If you are looking to rollback the database as well, I'm afraid it's not possible unless you have been backing up the database. I assume you are not backing up your database if you are deploying to `meteor.com`